# PROC MEANS compare with the results from the previous report

Tags: sas

I runthe proc means table to show the average, etc. I play it every week, or is there a chance to build a report where it would compare the results, for example, the "-SREDNIA" from the previous week it will be Number 4 from column N ? If no proc means there is a chance of using another procedure?

```
PROC SQL;   
  create table POLICY_VINTAGE_WEEKLY as
  select 
  POLICY_VINTAGE
 ,count(NRB) as NUMBER_POLICY
 ,today() as Run_Date format weeku.
  from PolisyEnd
  where POLIS="W"
  group by 
  POLICY_VINTAGE
;

Quit;
proc transpose data   = policy_vintage_weekly
              name= Polisy_Active
              out    = work.policy_vintage_weekly;
      by Run_Date;
   id policy_vintage;
proc append base=_work.policy_vintage_weekly data=policy_vintage_weekly force;
run;
proc means data=_work.policy_vintage_weekly;

run;
```

[image]

Comment: What in your data identifies one week data from the other?

Comment: I just run the code and proc append adds a column to the file

Comment: Does your raw data have a date field that you can use to aggregate by weeks? If not you need to explain how your data is structured more. For example, if your source file is changing every week and only has new data that's a different type of ETL process required.

Comment: "Column N" is the volume of rows found. I suggest you need to examine the dataset `_work.policy_vintage_weekly` to see if its contents make sense?
I get the feeling you did not write this process, so understanding what the data represents will help you. Nonetheless, you can compare the values in `_work.policy_vintage_weekly` with those of the new data `policy_vintage_weekly` by producing a means for each separately and compare them by eye.
I think you need to be much more specific to get an answer that is meaningful to you :)